# Vendors black box function can only be called successfully once

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

(first question here, sorry if I am breaking a piece of etiquette)

My site is running on an eCommerce back end provider that I subscribe to. They have everything in classic ASP. They have a black box function called import_products that I use to import a given text file into my site's database.

The problem is that if I call the function more than once, something breaks. Here is my example code:

```
for blah = 1 to 20

    thisfilename = "fullcatalog_" & blah & ".csv"
    Response.Write thisfilename & "<br>"
    Response.Flush
    Call Import_Products(3,thisfilename,1)  
Next
Response.End
```

The first execution of the Import_Products function works fine. The second time I get:
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
Subscript out of range: 'i'

The filenames all exist. That part is fine. There are no bugs in my calling code. I have tried checking the value of "i" before each execution. The first time the value is blank, and before the second execution the value is "2". So I tried setting it to null during each loop iteration, but that didn't change the results at all.

I assume that the function is setting a variable or opening a connection during its execution, but not cleaning it up, and then not expecting it to already be set the second time. Is there any way to find out what this would be? Or somehow reset the condition back to nothing so that the function will be 'fresh'?

The function is in an unreadable include file so I can't see the code. Obviously a better solution would be to go with the company support, and I have a ticket it in with them, but it is like pulling teeth to get them to even acknowledge that there is a problem. Let alone solve it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a further simplified example of calling the function. The first call works. The second call fails with the same error as above.

```
thisfilename = "fullcatalog_testfile.csv"
Call Import_Products(3,thisfilename,1)
Call Import_Products(3,thisfilename,1)
Response.End
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way anyone could help you without knowing details of the implementation of the `Import_Products` sub. That's why I voted to close.

Comment: "So I tried setting it to null during each loop iteration" - Did you try setting it to `0`?

The `i` not being reset is almost certainly your problem, and is a foolish coding mistake if it turns out to be the case.

Comment: Yes, I tried setting it to 0 as well.

Comment: Just checking, you never know.... Really need to get visibility on the function, it's doing something wrong with the `i` but without seeing what it's doing it's going to be hard to work out what, sorry.

Comment: Vendor replied to ticket and said that I was right but that it wasn't designed to be accessed more than once per page so that they wouldn't fix it :/

Answer (score 2):

The likely cause of the error are the two numeric parameters for the Import_Products subroutine.

```
Import_Products(???, FileName, ???)
```

The values are 3 and 1 in your example but you never explain what they do or what they are documented to do.

**EDIT** Since correcting the vender subroutine is impossible, but it always works for the first time it's called lets use an HTTP REDIRECT instead of a FOR LOOP so that it technically only gets called once per page execution.

```
www.mysite.tld/import.asp?current=1&end=20

curr = CInt(Request.QueryString("current"))
end = CInt(Request.QueryString("end"))
If curr <= end Then
    thisfilename = "fullcatalog_" & curr & ".csv"
    Call Import_Products(3,thisfilename,1)
    Response.Redirect("www.mysite.tld/import.asp?current=" & (curr + 1) & "&end=" & end)
End If
```

*note* the above was written inside my browser and is untested so syntax errors may exist.

Comment: Well, I believe one option is what table to import to, and the other option is to update only, or update/insert. I was told to only use 3 and 1 when calling the function, though.  I made a further simplified example of calling the function to demonstrate it, added to the original question. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @user1281743 - I'm not done yet, I'll update my answer with a mitigation strategy for you.

Comment: This is interesting. I am going to make one more effort to see if I can get the vendor to acknowledge the problem and fix their sub. If not I will implement some kind of workaround involving a redirect. Thanks! (Too bad I can't upvote yet with my newbie account)

Comment: I tried a simple implementation of this. One ?action1 that simply sets the working file to the test file, and the runs it through Import_Products. and an ?action2 that just calls Response.Redirect(mysite/import.asp?action1). To this I get the error of:     Response object error 'ASP 0156 : 80004005'
    Header Error
    The HTTP headers are already written to the client browser. Any HTTP header modifications must be made before writing page content. --- Note that there is only one .asp file that I can customize, it's a limitation of this vendor

Comment: @user1281743 - If you have any Response.Writes or other calls before your Response.Redirect it won't work. Your Response.Redirect needs to appear before anything is output written (even HTML) to the page. OR you can just Response.Write an IFRAME tag that has the SRC attribute pointed to the new URL.